# CakePHP linking a hasMany relationship with a different index

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have a table of securities like so:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `securities` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ticker` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(180) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ticker` (`ticker`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=585 ;
```

I.e. the primary key is `id` whilst there is another unique index `ticker`.

The `ticker` index refers to my other table, secuity_prices which has this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `security_prices` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `price_date` date NOT NULL,
  `ticker` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(10,6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=88340 ;
```

I want to define a hasMany relationship between them such that security hasMany securityPrice [securityPrice belongsTo security].

The problem I am having is that Cake is using the primary key of `security` to link to the `security_prices` table instead of the `ticker` field. How can I get the join to be made via the ticker?

Here are my relationships:

```
//Security
  public $hasMany = array(
    'SecurityPrice' => array(
        'className' => 'SecurityPrice',
        'foreignKey' => 'ticker',
        )
    );

//SecurityPrice
public $belongsTo = array(
        'Security' =>
            array(
                'className' => 'Security',
                'foreignKey' => 'ticker',
            )
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use $hasMany to do this, because those associations require that you follow Cake's naming conventions for the primary key. You are trying to join two tables via non-primary key columns. That can be done, but not via Cake's automatic associations.

You need to add the join conditions when performing a find operation or pagination operation.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables

```php
$options['joins'] = array(
    array('table' => 'security_prices',
        'alias' => 'SecurityPrice',
        'type' => 'LEFT',
        'conditions' => array(
            'Security.ticker = SecurityPrice.ticker',
        )
    )
);

$Security->find('all', $options);
```

If you have to do this often, then you should create a custom find type.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#creating-custom-find-types

```php
class Security extends AppModel {
   public $findMethods = array('ticker' =>  true);

   protected function _findTicker($state, $query, $results = array()) {
      if ($state === 'before') {
          $query['joins'][] = array(
              array('table' => 'security_prices',
                  'alias' => 'SecurityPrice',
                  'type' => 'LEFT',
                  'conditions' => array(
                      'Security.ticker = SecurityPrice.ticker',
                  )
              )
          );
          return $query;
       }
      return $results;
   }
}
```

Then later it's easy to find with the join.

```php
 $Security->find('ticker',.....);
```